# How come this JQuery loop doesn't change CSS with elements less than 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops, if-statement

Why doesn't this script loop trough every ul.products element and count li.product element and then change it's css(background to yellow).

When I change < to > then background color changes to all elements. So far I know that the problem is with this script checking every parent elements ul.products but is able to count li.product.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.products').each(function() {
    if ($('li.product').length < 4) {
      $("li.product").css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="products">
  <li class="product">Test</li>
  <li class="product">Test</li>
  <li class="product">Test</li>
  <li class="product">Test</li>
  <li class="product">Test</li>
</ul>

<ul class="products">
  <li class="product">Test</li>
  <li class="product">Test</li>
  <li class="product">Test</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p9rsuhx3/2/

Comment: Sorry about this, somehow the jsfiddle didn't save and I put the old link. Check it now @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I added an answer below.

Comment: use **if ($('li.product', this).length < 4)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because your code looks at all `.product` elements in the DOM, not specifically those within each `ul` in the `each()` loop.

To correct this you can use `$(this)` to reference the current `ul`, then retrieve its child `li` elements:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('ul.products').each(function() {
    let $li = $(this).children('.product');
    if ($li.length < 4) {
      $li.css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="products">
  <li class="product">Test</li>
  <li class="product">Test</li>
  <li class="product">Test</li>
  <li class="product">Test</li>
  <li class="product">Test</li>
</ul>

<ul class="products">
  <li class="product">Test</li>
  <li class="product">Test</li>
  <li class="product">Test</li>
</ul>
```

As an aside, note that jQuery 1.9.1 is very outdated, over 8 years in fact. The latest version, at time of writing this answer, is 3.6.0. I would suggest updating to that.

Comment: Spot on! Thank you for the answer and also pretty interesting solution.

Comment: No problem, glad to help